# cursor to get the desired result

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table like this:

```
x------x---------x----------------------x-------x
|  Id  |   ACCTNO  |   name2             |  QTY  |
x------x---------x----------------------x-------x
|   1  |   1     | here is 2014-01-13   |  10   |
|   1  |   2     | there are 2014-01-12  |  20   |
|   2  |   3     | 2014-01-08           |  40    |
|   2  |   4     | 2014-01-06           |  30    |
x------x---------x----------------------x-------x
```

I'm trying to get the records where English alphabets are there along with date.

Im trying to do this like:

```
DECLARE @ACCTNO as INT;
DECLARE @name2 as varchar(max);
declare @st varchar(max)

DECLARE @BusinessCursor as CURSOR;


SET @BusinessCursor = CURSOR FOR
SELECT ACCTNO, Name2
FROM DPBENCHA2;

  OPEN @BusinessCursor;
   FETCH NEXT FROM @BusinessCursor INTO @ACCTNO, @name2;
    --PRINT  @Name2;

     WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
     BEGIN

     set @st = @Name2;
     select SUBSTRING(@st, patindex('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]%', @st), 50)
      PRINT @st;
     FETCH NEXT FROM @BusinessCursor INTO @ACCTNO,@st;
    END

   CLOSE @BusinessCursor;
   DEALLOCATE @BusinessCursor;
```

Here instead of getting the records that contains English alphabet along with date. I'm getting all records. How to resolve this? How can I get the records only for account number 1 and 2? Is there any other ways to do it.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm trying to get the records where English alphabets are there along with date.

You seem to want a simple query:

```
SELECT ACCTNO, Name2
FROM DPBENCHA2
WHERE name2 LIKE '%[a-zA-Z]%';
```

This is much simpler than a cursor.  In general, you want to avoid cursors in SQL.

EDIT:

If you want to extract the date from `Name2`:

```
SELECT ACCTNO, Name2,
       SUBSTRING(name2,
                 PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%'),
                 10) as thedate
FROM DPBENCHA2
WHERE name2 LIKE '%[a-zA-Z]%';
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the records where English alphabets are there **along with date.**

Answer (score 0):

Use as following

```
SUBSTRING(@st, patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%', @st), 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a simple select, assuming your date format is `yyyy-dd-mm` or `yyyy-mm-dd`

```
select * from DPBENCHA2 where  (name2 like '%[a-z]%')

 and name2 like '% [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%'
```

note the space in `'%<space>[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%'`

this will ensure that `'some alphabet 22323-12-34'` will not be included in your select